# Web browser extension common files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome/Firefox/Safari extension and I want to reuse the same code on each. I have a background script, an injected script, an iframe, .. And they will be the same for each extension, so I wanted to build something like:

```
root folder
|- chrome
|  |- manifest.json
|  |- ...
|  \  ...
|
|- firefox
|  \  ...
|
|- safari
|  \  ...
|
\ common
   |- iframe
   |
   |- scripts
   |  |- injectedscript.js
   |  \  backgroundscript.js
   |
   \  ...
```

So when I add my backgroundscript.js in my manifest.json for chrome like so:

```
"background" : {
  "scripts" : [
        "../../common/scripts/backgroundscript.js"
    ]
}
```

But Chrome keep telling me: `Could not load background script '../../common/scripts/backgroundscript.js'`

Do you know if there is a reason (maybe a Chrome Extension cannot load file in it's parent folder)? And do you think this is a good way to procede?

Answer (score 4):

Chrome extension considers the folder in which `manifest.json` is as its root. You cannot traverse upwards from there.

Comment: Ok, that's what I though. Still, I wasn't able to find a piece of documentation talking about it... Do you have a reference ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. But consider this: for a packed extension, the requirement is that `manifest.json` is in the root of the package.

Comment: Ok, Ok, I will use grunt to sync files for the 3 extensions so, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, have a separate process that assembles the structure for publishing.